# how does 何の部活もやってこなかったもんね mean you've never been in any kind of club

Tags: meaning, anime

I was watching the first episode of the anime k-on and I saw this

> こうやってニートが出来上がっていくのね、**何の部活もやってこなかったもんね**

the subs said that the sentence meant

> that's how people become neets

I'm confused by this firstly why use いく here

> こうやってニートが出来上がって**いく**のね

doesn't the 出来上がる already mean to complete or become

and my other confusion

> 何の部活もやってこなかったもんね

I don't understand why this means you haven't been in any clubs with my current understanding I would say its

> what clubs have you not done

or

> what clubs didn't you do

which is wrong but I don't get why what am i missing

Answer (score 2, accepted):

いく in 出来上がっていく describes a process of change that goes on into the future. こうやってニートが出来上がるのね is also fine. いく adds a nuance that this process, of neets being created like that, will continue. She may have in mind other people like the person she is talking to becoming neets through a similar process.

部活をする or 部活をやる refers to the act of engaging in some activity as a member of a club at school. 部活 here is the object of the verb する or やる.

You should understand 何の部活もやらない the same way you would other sentences with a question word like 何 and も, such as 何も食べない.

何の部活もやってこなかった describes a process that has led to the current state in this context. So the translation seems correct.